# ffplay how to play HEVC or H264 with hardware acceleration on Mac?

Tags: ffmpeg

In FFmpeg, I can specific encoder by `-c:v h264_videotoolbox` to use Videotoolbox with GPU acceleration to do transcode.

But I don't know what commands I should give to ffplay to utilize Videotoolbox with hardware decoding?

```
ffplay -hwaccel_flags my.mp4 // no GPU usage up
ffplay -pixel_format videotoolbox_vld my.mp4 // Option pixel_format not found
ffplay -decoders | grep "box" // only decoders with (AudioToolbox) shows
ffplay -buildconf // the --enable-videotoolbox is showed
```

Comment: What's the output of `ffplay -decoders | grep "264"`

Comment: only one row: "VFS..D h264 H.264/AVC/MPEG-4 AVC/MPEG-4 part10". It does not indicate whether it support HW or not.
ffplay/ffmpeg is installed from brew. I also tried static build from official site and build from GitHub source code in 4.2 branch. Those seems the same.

Comment: My platform is iMac 21" 4K 2019. Tested another App, when playing the HEVC on VLC app, the I have GPU rate raised to 70%~80%.

Answer (score 5):

You can pipe the result of `ffmpeg` to `ffplay`. I tested on an 1080p video using VAAPI acceleration, the CPU rate decreased about 10% altogether.

See [HWAccelIntro](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) here. It talks about `ffmpeg`, but you can pipe the result of `ffmpeg` to `ffplay`.

For example, play *test.mp4* using VAAPI on Linux:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -i test.mp4 \
-vcodec rawvideo -acodec copy -f matroska - | ffplay -i -
```

Use `rawvideo` for video encoding, and use `-f` to specify a container. `Videotoolbox` should be similar. If you managed to decode a video with `Videotoolbox` in ffmpeg, just pipe to `ffplay` in this way.