# ffmpeg play youtube hls m3u8 with hardware acceleration

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, hls

(1) I get the hls/m3u8 url from video ID with yt-dlp.

(2) I play the hls/m3u8 url with ffmpeg/ffplay.

```
ffplay "https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_playlist/.../playlist/index.m3u8"
```

It works, but `sudo intel_gpu_top` shows `Video 0.00%` i.e. it is rendered in software only.

How do I enable hardware video acceleration (vaapi) without mpv?

GPU is Intel HD Graphics 520 (i5-6200U).

**edit 1**

I tried adapting this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1506651/) to a similar question:

```
ffmpeg \
  -hwaccel vaapi \
  -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 \
  -i "https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_playlist/.../playlist/index.m3u8" \
  -vcodec rawvideo \
  -an \
  -f matroska \
  - | ffplay -i -
```

It did not work. It causes high CPU usage and the video playback was choppy.